# How to access command-line outside lxde?

Tags: command-line, login, arch-linux, lxde

I am a beginner to Arch Linux. I installed arch following a youtube tutorial and also the official arch wiki. I set the lxdm package to load by default. But when I try to log in with an id and password, the screen goes blank and then the login screen appears again. I tried searching for a solution but I do not know how to access the terminal/command line now that the system boots to lxdm directly.

Comment: does Ctrl + Alt + F1 bring up a virtual terminal you can login to?

Comment: In Arch Linux, you should always have a backup DE in order to login in case the main one you use breaks. My main DE ise lxqt and I use lxde for backing lxqt whenever it breaks occasionally for a short interval after some updates.